# Sequelize converts automatically float value 1.36 to 1.3599999999999999

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm writing an API to get values from MARIADB(10.4.8) by Sequelize. 
In Sequelize I have defined the data type as FLOAT, also in table structure it is FLOAT.

When I try to read the value "1.36", it automatically converts it to "1.3599999999999999".
I have tried 1.37, 1.35, 1.38 etc but this **conversion**, if you will, happens only in case the value is 1.36. [Image File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed7mf.png)

It's weird but if anyone can explain why this might be happening, that would be great.